# If value in column B for a certain ID in column A has been defined, update all values for this ID in column B (Bigquery SQL)

Tags: sql, google-bigquery

I have a simple table as a result of the following query...

```
select clientId cid, customDimensions.value way4id
from mytable
where customDimensions.index = 2 and customDimensions.value != 'undefined'
group by customDimensions.value, cid 
order by cid asc
limit 100;
```

... that looks like this

```
cid    | way4id
------ | ------
a      | not set
b      | 123
b      | not set
c      | not set
d      | 1234
d      | not set
```

What I want is to run an *update* query so to get this

```
cid    | way4id
------ | ------
a      | not set
b      | 123
b      | 123
c      | not set
d      | 1234
d      | 1234
```

Can't get my head around this. A subquery? A loop?

Thanks!

--

Seems like this is working

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  clientId cid,
  COALESCE (MAX(CASE WHEN cd.value != 'not set' THEN cd.value END) OVER (PARTITION BY clientId), 'not set') way4id
FROM `mytable`, UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd
WHERE TRUE
  AND cd.index = 2
  AND cd.value != 'undefined'
ORDER BY cid asc
LIMIT 100;
```

Just wondering how I can use update-set syntax to update this.

Trying do smth like this to update, but nothing works

```
#standardSQL
UPDATE (SELECT
  clientId cid,
  COALESCE (MAX(CASE WHEN cd.value != 'not set' THEN cd.value END) OVER (PARTITION BY clientId), 'not set') way4id
FROM `akbars-ru-data-streaming.akbars_ru_data_streaming_maximp.stream_max`, UNNEST(customDimensions) as cd
WHERE TRUE
  AND cd.index = 2
  AND cd.value != 'undefined'
ORDER BY cid asc
LIMIT 100) as t1
SET way4id = IF(t2.way4id IS NOT NULL, t2.way4id, 'not set')
FROM (
    SELECT cid, max(CASE WHEN way4id != 'not set' THEN way4id END) way4id FROM `yourTable` group by cid) t2
WHERE t1.cid = t2.cid
```

Could you fix the query?

Answer (score 1, accepted):

This might give you what you want in a straightforward manner:

```
#standardSQL
SELECT
  clientId cid,
  COALESCE(MAX(CASE WHEN customDimensions.value != 'not set' THEN customDimensions.value END) OVER(PARTITION BY clientId), 'not set') way4id
FROM `mytable`
WHERE TRUE
  AND customDimensions.index = 2
  AND customDimensions.value != 'undefined'
ORDER BY cid asc
LIMIT 100;
```

You can test with simulated data like so:

```
#standardSQL
WITH `mytable` AS(
  SELECT 'a' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (2, 'not set') customDimensions UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (3, '3') customDimensions UNION ALL
  SELECT 'a' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (2, 'undefined') customDimensions UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (2, '123') customDimensions UNION ALL
  SELECT 'b' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (2, 'not set') customDimensions UNION ALL
  SELECT 'c' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (2, 'not set') customDimensions UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (2, '1234') customDimensions UNION ALL
  SELECT 'd' AS clientID, STRUCT<index INT64, value STRING> (2, 'not set') customDimensions
)
```

Which results in:

```
Row cid way4id   
1   a   not set  
2   b   123  
3   b   123  
4   c   not set  
5   d   1234     
6   d   1234
```

Instead of running the query and then having an `UPDATE` operation on the result set it might be easier to just bring the desired output in the first query.

If you still want to use an `UPDATE` syntax, you could use something like:

```
UPDATE `yourTable` t1
SET way4id = IF(t2.way4id IS NOT NULL, t2.way4id, 'not set')
FROM (SELECT cid, max(CASE WHEN way4id != 'not set' THEN way4id END) way4id FROM `yourTable` group by cid) t2
WHERE t1.cid = t2.cid
```

Where `yourTable` already has the results of `cid` and `way4id` from your first original query. Keep in mind though that the best approach is to avoid DML operations in BQ if you can solve your tasks using regular queries already.

Comment: That could be an option, but _mytable_ contains about a million rows. How can we solve that in this case?

Comment: I'm not sure what you mean. For this answer, `mytable` is just a simulation of your actual table, so you can just ignore the first part and use your table instead. Other than that, I wonder if you found performance issues maybe?

Comment: I edited my answer, maybe it's a bit more clear now.

Comment: **Error: Encountered " "OVER" "OVER "" at line 3, column 95. Was expecting: ")" ...**

This is what I get when trying to run the query. Hmm... seems like all "()" are on their places

Comment: Just wondering, are you using Standard SQL? You could add `#standardSQL` right at the beginning of the query to see if it works

Comment: Just added the example

Comment: How would you combine these two in a single UPDATE query?

Comment: Hmm not sure. I imagine you first need to create the table and then run the update. Don't know if running everything at once would be possible

Answer (score 0):

You can write subquery which will result defined values I am assuming there would be only one defined value and non defined would be nulls so I have kept condition as "not null", then join the subset with main table to get the defined values from subset of query .

```
SELECT clientid, subset.val FROM mytable LEFT JOIN (SELECT clientid AS id,
way4id AS val FROM mytable WHERE way4id IS NOT null) subset ON subset.id=clientid;
```